# Question on Fermat numbers and Wiefrich primes

Tags: number-theory

Theorem 6.25. in the book 17 Lectures on 
Fermat NUmbers From Number Theory to Geometry states:

If there exist only finitely many Wieferich primes, then there 
exist infinitely many Fermat numbers that are not powerful.

Does that mean if someone proves that Fermat Numbers are square free then it is proven that  there are only finitely many Wieferich primes?

Thank you

Comment: I guess it will also prove that also all Mersenne Numbers are square free. (Theorem 6.26 from the same book.)So one proof takes out 3 Open problems in Number Theory. Am I right?

Comment: +1 Interesting. What does "powerful" mean?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number says:A powerful number is a positive integer m such that for every prime number p dividing m, p^2 also divides m.So if a number is not powerful then its square free,

Comment: @Kurtul: That last statement is not quite true. According to the definition $12=2^2\cdot 3$ is not powerful, but certainly also not squarefree.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. However, in the case for Mersenne and Fermat Numbers, their divisors are always odd primes. So for them, if they are not powerful, they are square-free.

Comment: (to your last comment) No. Consider the number $n=p_1^{k_1} p_2^{k_2} \dots p_r^{k_r}$ where as usual the $p_i$ are _distinct_ prime numbers. Then square-free means that $k_i < 2$ for ***all*** $i$. And powerful means that $k_i \ge 2$ for ***all*** $i$. It often happens that some of the exponents $k_i$ are less than two while others are greater than or equal to two, and in that case $n$ is neither square-free nor powerfull. For example $45=3^2\cdot 5$ is odd and neither square-free nor powerful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fermat numbers are *pairwise coprime*. So given one prime number $p$ (either Wieferich or non-Wieferich), there are only two possibilities: Either:

1. $p$ divides one Fermat number $F_m$ but divides no *other* Fermat numbers, or
2. $p$ divides no Fermat numbers at all

For example $114689$ (non-Wieferich) divides $F_{12}$ and no other Fermat numbers, while $114691$ (non-Wieferich) divides no Fermat number.

(The two known Wieferich primes are in case (2) above, so they do not divide Fermat numbers, but it is conceivable that other Wieferich primes exist that belong to case (1).)

Now consider a prime $p$ and a Fermat number $F_m$ that are so related (i.e. we assume $p|F_m$), then the following two statements are equivalent:

- $p^2|F_m$, the *square* of $p$ divides the associated Fermat number
- $p$ is a Wieferich prime

---

It is ***thought*** that infinitely many non-Wieferich primes exist, and it is likewise thought that infinitely many Wieferich primes exist.

Suppose the first of these conjectures is false. Then all primes, with a finite set of exceptions, are actually Wieferich. It follows that all but finitely many Fermat numbers are entirely composed of Wieferich primes. That means that all but finitely many Fermat numbers are [powerful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powerful_number), i.e. on the form $a^2b^3$ for some integers $a,b$. This seems very unlikely, but nobody has disproved it. It would also follow that almost all (only finitely many excpetions) [pernicious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pernicious_number) Mersenne numbers are powerful (in particular composite).

Until now, no Fermat number is known that is not square-free, so just one single instance of a powerful Fermat number would be a tremendous surprise.

Let us turn to the other conjecture, on the infinitude of the Wieferich primes. Suppose that conjecture turns out to be false. Then all, with the possible exception of finitely many, Fermat numbers are square-free. In particular, if $\{1093,3511\}$ is the full set of Wieferich primes, then absolutely all Fermat numbers are square-free (since $1093$ and $3511$ belong to case (2) above).

Remember that even if infinitely many Wieferich primes exist, as conjectured, that does not say anything about how many of them will divide Fermat numbers (or divide pernicious Mersenne numbers).

You:

> Does that mean if someone proves that Fermat Numbers are square free
>   then it is proven that there are only finitely many Wieferich primes?

No. If someone proves that all Fermat numbers are square-free, the implication is only that every Wieferich prime fails to divide a Fermat number. I.e. it would follow that every Wieferich prime is in case (2) above.

Answer (score 3):

No, it doesn't. The proposition

"If there exists only finitely many Wieferich primes, then there exists infinitely many Fermat numbers that are not powerful"

is still true when the conclusion is true but the premise is false.

Comment: This is sound logic. Also, some Wieferich primes, like the two known ones, 1093 and 3511, divide no Fermat number and no Mersenne number (where a Mersenne number is required here to have prime exponent). There is nothing known that rules out the possibility that infinitely many Wieferich primes exist, but all of them fail to divide any Fermat number.

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research I have found http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime#Connection_with_Mersenne_and_Fermat_primes. There it is stated that

> " ***if there are only finitely many Wieferich primes, then there will be at most finitely many Mersenne numbers that are not square-free. Rotkiewicz showed that the converse is also true, that is, if there are infinitely many square-free Mersenne numbers, then there are infinitely many non-Wieferich primes.[37]***
>   "

and Theorem 6.26 from the book states if Fermat numbers are square free, so are Mersenne Numbers (or at least this is what I Understood).
 So I take it as: "If Fermat Numbers are square free, then Mersenne Numbers are square free, then there are infinitely many non-Wieferich primes!

Is my understanding valid?

Comment: Not quite. If (infinitely many) Fermat numbers are square-free, then infinitely many non-Wieferich primes exist. There could be infinitely many Wieferich primes at the same time, or there could be only finitely many. Similarly, if (infinitely many) pernicious Mersenne numbers are square-free (for example if infinitely many Mersenne primes exist), then infinitely many non-Wieferichs exist. Again that says nothing about the number of Wieferichs. // It is possible that all Fermat numbers are square-free while at the same time some Mersenne numbers are not square-free.